# net4india server Internal Server Error - Login Page Error

Tags: servlets, internal-server-error

I have uploaded sample project of checking the connectivity of database in net4india.

In eclipse it working fine however when deployed to server through .war file it is not working giving the below error.

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your reques
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@xxxxxx.in to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log**

I am posting the complete code below. Please verify and suggest me the solution.

```
                1) Servlet location is: LoginExample\src\com\journaldev\servlet\LoginServlet.java
                2) Web.xml location is: LoginExample\WebContent\WEB-INF
                3) Login.html & LoingSuccess.jsp: LoginExample\WebContent
                4) jdbc.properties location is: LoginExample\build\classes
                [Above locations are as per folderwise]

                just to reconfirm, it is working fine in eclipse however it is once I deploy it, it is giving the error. Please help me out.

                LoginSuccess.jsp



                <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
                pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
                <title>Login Success Page</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h3>Hi ABC, Login successful.</h3>
                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                </body>
                </html>**strong text**

                login.html


                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="US-ASCII">
                <title>Login Page</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

                Username: <input type="text" name="user">
                <br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>



                jdbc.properties


                driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                url=jdbc:mysql://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:3306/abc
                user=abc
                password=abc

                LoginServlet.java                

                package com.journaldev.servlet;

                import java.io.IOException;


                import java.io.PrintWriter;

                import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
                import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
                import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

                /**
                * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
                */
                @WebServlet(
                description = "Login Servlet", 
                urlPatterns = { "/LoginServlet" }, 
                initParams = { 
                @WebInitParam(name = "user", value = "xyz"), 
                @WebInitParam(name = "password", value = "xyz")
                })
                public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


                public void init() throws ServletException {
                //we can create DB connection resource here and set it to Servlet context
                if(getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbURL").equals("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:3306/abc") &&
                getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbUser").equals("abc") &&
                getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbUserPwd").equals("abc"))
                getServletContext().setAttribute("DB_Success", "True");

                else throw new ServletException("DB Connection error");
                }


                protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                //get request parameters for userID and password
                String user = request.getParameter("user");
                String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

                //get servlet config init params
                String userID = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("user");
                String password = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("password");
                //logging example
                log("User="+user+"::password="+pwd);

                if(userID.equals(user) && password.equals(pwd)){
                response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
                }else{
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
                rd.include(request, response);

                }

                }

                }


                web.xml


                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
                <display-name>LoginExample</display-name>
                <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
                </welcome-file-list>

                <context-param>
                <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
                <param-value>jdbc:mysql://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:3306/abc</param-value>
                </context-param>
                <context-param>
                <param-name>dbUser</param-name>
                <param-value>abc</param-value>
                </context-param>
                <context-param>
                <param-name>dbUserPwd</param-name>
                <param-value>abc</param-value>
                </context-param>
                </web-app>


                Thank you very much in advance for your help.
```

Comment: did you **contact the server administrator**?

Comment: Since I am new to this forum I have pasted the code as well as my comments. Kindly ignore my text in code snippet. I have provided the name of the file followed by the code. Please verify and kindly help.

Comment: Yes Plutonix. I got a response stating that, there is no issue from there end and it will work fine but no luck. What can be the issue from server side?

Comment: Your error message says there may be some server log information available. What does that information show?

Comment: I am sorry. There is no server log information available to access. I deploying the project through filezilla and I am not sure how to view serverlogs. what can be the possible problem problem with this ?

Comment: Just to confirm, I am using phpmyadmin.net4india.com it is not on local system. when I login to phpmyadmin I found the below error.
"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."

when I clicked the option I see that all are in disabled status.

Also I see the error " The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret)."